# Is screw/nut zinc vs zinc plating as advertise or a manufacturer shorthand?

Tags: screws, materials

I bought a set of machine screws and nuts which say "zinc" on the product. I also bought a box of locknuts from a different manufacturer which says "zinc plated" on it.

Is the box of "zinc" 100% zinc or is this a manufacturer shorthand for zinc plated?

I am unfamiliar with what to expect with this material. Brass and stainless steel seem to be otherwise straightforward.

Comment: if it sticks to magnets it's zinc plated steel, post a photo of the box that says zinc

Comment: Yup, the magnet test will eliminate the slight possibility that you have solid zinc hardware. There are two typical approaches to galvanizing (zinc coating) - plating is one, and leaves a thin shiny layer. "Hot dip" galvanizing leaves a thicker, rougher layer. Both are usually applied to steel hardware.

Comment: Very unlikely to be solid zinc  as  it is much lower strength than steel  ( like  10%  of steel)..

Answer (score 0):

Zinc plated is the most common type of corrosion protection for machined steel parts. There are several different types of plating that can look silver to yellow. Hot dipped process is more common in lag screws and some nails it is usually dull silver and normally a thicker coating than a plated screw or nut. Since brass and stainless don’t corrode like plain steel they don’t require a protective coating.